# Javascript / Vue JS - Retrieve value of all elements in object

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an object that retrieves 4 different elements with different numerical values.
I'm trying to access and retrieve all these numerical values.

The object returns the following:

```
{__ob__: Observer}
  collectedTrashCount: 139
  dangerousAreaCount: 11
  schoolCount: 5
  trashBinCount: 44
```

If I want to retrieve the value of the `collectedTrashCount`, I would simply do the following:

```
computed: {
    dashboardList: function () {
      return this.$store.getters.getDashboard;
    },
    checkCount: function () {
      console.log(this.dashboardList.collectedTrashCount);
    }
  },
```

The `console.log` in this case would give me `139`.

My question is: What should I do to return all these values such as: `139`, `11`, `5`, `44`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `entries` method to map that values in an array :

```
checkCount: function () {
   return Object.entries(this.dashboardList).map(([key, val]) => val)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way that doesn't require mapping is using [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values):

```js
const obj = {
  collectedTrashCount: 139,
  dangerousAreaCount: 11,
  schoolCount: 5,
  trashBinCount: 44,
}
const values = Object.values(obj)
console.log(values)
```